# iBatis query object with a nested list of objects

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, ibatis

I have an POJO with multiple fields. One of the fields is a List.
Some of the fields in first POJO will have same values as fields in SecondPojo.

I want to get a List with one query. Whoever wrote the code in the past was getting a List and doing a query to fetch List for each object inside List which defeats the purpose of using a database.

How can I do this in iBatis?

This is the result map I have currently which I assume is correct.

```
<resultMap id="example" type="FirstPojo">
    <id property="headerId" column="id"/>
    <result property="field1" column="field_one"></result>
...

    <collection property="example2" ofType="SecondPojo">
        <id property="versionId" column="id"/>
        <result property="field1" column="field_one"></result>
...
    </collection>
```

The question is how do I go on about writing the query?
FirstPojo and SecondPojo data are in different tables.

This is what I have right now which isn't working.

```
Select 

h.id as "headerId"
v.field_one as "field1"

v.id as "versionId"
v.field_one as "field1"

FROM account.first_pojo h
JOIN account.second_pojo v
```